# Не могу поставить связь по ключам MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Структура БД и ошибка в этой теме - [Тыкайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1203767/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BC-mssql)

Данные БД (не углубляйтесь в украинский язык, кто его не знает, в колонке nameLocality - названия городов):

Dimension2:
[image]

Dimension3 (тут не только один город, там их много, ибо 25к записей):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Fact:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и собственно сделать я хочу связь от fact к dimension2 по ключу KOATUU, а от dimension3 к dimension2 по nameLocality.
Буду весьма благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, она была в том, что нужно было удалить в fact & dimension3 данные которых нет в dimension2, а не наоборот.